# What are the part/section titles to Greg Keyes' Dark Genesis (Babylon 5) novel?

Tags: novel, babylon-5

This is the first book in his Psi Corps trilogy, and Keyes likes to break his books up into "parts" each of which are comprised of half a dozen chapters or so. There are 4 such parts.

Unfortunately, the copy I had was dog-eared and I was unaware of these having titles when I read it. The book is no longer in my possession, but I am curious whether there was anything clever in those names?

Can anyone enlighten me as to what those were?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section titles are:

- Part I - **Holocaust**
- Part II - **The Kith**
- Part III - **Resistance**
- Part IV - **Legacy**

Comment: FWIW, the book starts with a "prologue" and end with an "epilogue;" the parts have 6, 6, 11, and 6 chapters respectively.

Comment: @DavidW I'd tell you to throw up an answer and let me upvote it as well, but we'd get in trouble for that. I tend to upvote good faith answers period though, so if at some point in the future anyone wants to pretend they didn't realize another beat them to the punch, no one will be able to prove anything.

Comment: This one is fully on you. I had time to check my ebook version, realise that it's not got the headers, check the version on Google Books and realise it's not letting me see the headers and finally go and [grab a copy from Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/birthofpsicorps00keye).

Comment: @Valorum Thanks. Had no idea it was on archive.org.